# JQuery Datatable: Fit column width to content

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am building a DataTable on the fly, so I don't know the column content upfront. I would like to obtain a table for which each column width fits its content width.
I tried to manipulate "autoWidth", but it resizes columns according to their number and to the table width, but all columns have the same width.
How can I let each column adjust its width according to its own content?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`autoWidth: true`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/autoWidth) along with [`columns.adjust()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()) API method to adjust column width after you done adding data to the table.

Comment: "autoWidth": true    worked for me, without using columns.adjust()

Comment: appearently "autoWidth" is default to "true" i had to put it to "autoWidth": false and then use columns.adjust()

Comment: Yes, [autoWidth](https://datatables.net/reference/option/autoWidth) here in the doc said `autoWidth` default to `true`, so you don't have to set `autoWidth: true;`. You need to change it to `false`, then put `columns.adjust()` somewhere just after your data rendered in the Datatable.

Answer (score 1):

in my case,
i needed to   fit / collapse table width down to  the content.
`autowidth: true` wasn't enough. It also needed `display:inline-table` .

if i dont put inline-table,  table expands to full width of page.

```
    /*  put 2 tables side by side */ 
    .dataTables_wrapper {
        display: inline-table;

        /* below optional .*/
        --width: auto;
        --max-width: 45%;
    }
```